# Telerik RadGrid's paging section not refreshing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, telerik, paging, radgrid

I have a problem with a telerik RadGrid where the paging section is not refreshing. If, for example, the first search returns 15 records and the second search only 5 records, I see '... page 1 of 2...' in the second search which is incorrect info caused by the paging section of the grid not refreshing. My page count is set to 10 records. That means there should be only one page in the second search.

I am using Telerik.Web.UI version 2008.1.415.35 targeting .net 3.5 on Visual Studio 2008.

Please help as soon as possible.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather an old version of the Telerik AJAX controls - the current one is 2010.2.826. Move to it as they are probably various fixes compared to the version you use (dating two and a half years ago). I will not be surprised if the issue with the pager is fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Telerik older versions
As a workaround you can try this.

```
//dt is the data table;
grid1.dataSource=dt;
grid1.VirtualItemCount= dt.rows.count;
grid1.databind();
```